# How to get a free license key for VMWare FUSION Pro?

Tags: mac, virtual-machine, vmware, license, vmware-fusion

Downloaded VMware FUSION Pro 12 on Mac.

On the load page, these is a "Get a Free License Key" button.

[image: click here to see picture]

After click the button it redirected to this page: https://www.vmware.com/try-vmware.html?p=player&&/

How to do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=fusion-player-personal
It appears that was a bad link. I believe on Fusion is free, Fusion Pro likely is not. Above link seems to indicate you have to register a VMWare account t to get that free license. Hopefully it's that & not a 30 day trial. Link above was taken from Fusion product page:
https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/fusion-evaluation.html

Their blog post backs you up that it should be free:
https://blogs.vmware.com/teamfusion/2020/08/announcing-fusion-12-and-workstation-16.html

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem, so please clean cache or use an other Browser, after i used Safari i get the key by open the link:
https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/evalcenter?p=fusion-player-personal